# How to get what select statement returns in SQL's store procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have a store procedure that execute an "insert into" and then a "select".
I have used all fetch to get the select's value, but they don't work.

PHP code

sample.php

```
<?php
    /////////CALLING CONTROLLER (using require_once)///////////
    $controller = new Controller();
    $exam = $controller->getExample();
    $exam2 = $controller->getExample2('a');
?>

<label for="exam1">Example 1</label>
<input type="text" name="exam1" id="exam1" value="<?php echo $exam[0]["texto"] ?>" style="width: 300px">
<br>
<label for="exam2">Example 2</label>
<input type="text" name="exam2" id="exam2" value="<?php echo $exam2[0]["texto"] ?>" style="width: 300px">
```

Controller.php

```
<?php
    
    class Controller {
           
          public function getExample(){
            /////////////CREATING 'CONNECTION' TO CONNECT WITH MODEL//////////////
            $querySQL = "EXEC [dbo].[example]";
            $execQuery=$connection->prepare($querySQL);
            $execQuery->execute();
            return $execQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }


        public function getExample2($name){
            /////////////CREATING 'CONNECTION' TO CONNECT WITH MODEL//////////////
            $querySQL = "EXEC [dbo].[example2] ?";
            $execQuery=$connection->prepare($querySQL);
            $execQuery->bindValue(1, $name);
            $execQuery->execute();
            return $execQuery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

    }
```

SQL SERVER

```
CREATE PROCEDURE example
AS
SELECT 'whatever' as texto;

CREATE PROCEDURE example2
@name [nvarchar](40)
AS
INSERT INTO prueba
           ([name])
     VALUES
           (@name)
SELECT 'whatever2' as texto;
```

I think my mistake is in PHP's code.
My queries work well, about second procedure (example2), this inserts a new register ('a') successfully but when I try to call 'texto' returns me:
**Notice**: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs..., unlike first one (example returns 'whatever'). Please help, I don't know how to get texto's value in the second procedure

[image: image of the outcome]

And... I really apologize to the people who watched this question as answer in my previous post, I didn't know what I did was wrong

Comment: Add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to your proc .`

Comment: Hi master @DanGuzman I have added it, but the outcome is the same :c